# Best place to control column level permissions logic in app using django and postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I am building an app which allows users to create tables and set permissions for other users on each column (if required). The tables need to be auditable so that users can interrogate:

- who made changes;
- when;
- and what they were - this is to support a diffing feature.

Users will also be able to add columns to tables, and I am hoping to be able to automate all of this: creation of the table, permissions for columns, altering table to add new columns, creating triggers etc.

I am in the process of setting up the audit table automation with trigger functions. I started writing the permissions logic into the trigger functions but stopped when my approach started to get hacky:

- using hstore to loop over column headers (https://dbfiddle.uk/sRJf7ZBm);
- storing inserts in a string (https://dbfiddle.uk/gE5bqKWe) to be added if the user has permission for every column - I'm also concerned what impact this will have on types (I have other types besides text);
- I couldn't work out how to use transactions to commit or rollback if an error occurred, apparently this is only possible in procedures?
- I'm even considering creating a new table for each column and joining them together, but I fear this could create other problems, maybe reduce performance?

I know that postgres has the ability to set user permissions for tables by column and it seems as though using database permission system would be the more robust approach, but I don't know if it's possible to do this with django's authentication system.

Django's built in authentication system creates tables for users without actually creating users in the database. Right now, I'm only interacting with the database using the postgres user. Which means that the only way to control permissions is through the trigger functions or in the python application code itself.

The number of rows for any one table is never going to go beyond 100k, and in most cases will be < 1k.

I'm new to postgres and databases so I'm concerned about going too far down the wrong development path. Any help is hugely appreciated!

Answer (score -3):

Building a dynamic and auditable table system in a Django application with PostgreSQL can indeed be challenging, especially if you're new to databases. Your project involves multiple layers: dynamic table creation, column-based permissions, auditing changes, and integrating this with Django's authentication system. Let's break down your requirements and provide a strategy for each:

**1. Dynamic Table Creation and Modification**
Approach: Instead of creating physical tables for each user-defined table, consider using a more flexible schema. One common approach is the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model, where you can store different "entities" (your dynamic tables) and their "attributes" (columns) in a more generic structure.
Benefits: Easier to manage dynamically, especially when adding new columns or tables.

**2. Column-based Permissions**
Approach: Managing permissions at the column level in PostgreSQL can get complex. Instead, handle this logic in your Django application. Create a permissions model that ties users, tables, and columns together, specifying what each user can do with each column.
Benefits: Easier to integrate with Django's authentication system and more flexible.

**3. Auditing (Change Tracking)**
Approach: Use a separate audit table or even a separate schema to track changes. You can use triggers in PostgreSQL to log changes to this audit table. Alternatively, handle this in Django using signal listeners for post_save and post_delete events.
Benefits: Provides a clear history of changes without cluttering your main data tables.

**4. Using Django with PostgreSQL**
Concern: Django's built-in auth system doesn't create database-level users, which complicates using PostgreSQL's native column-level permissions.
Solution: Handle permissions in your Django application. Use Django's user and groups system to define and check permissions at the application level.
Implementation Strategy
Schema Design: Implement an EAV model or a similar flexible structure for your user-defined tables.
Permissions Model: Create a Django model to store permissions for users on each column of these dynamic tables.
Audit Trail: Implement audit logging either via PostgreSQL triggers or Django signals.
User Authentication and Permissions: Utilize Django's user authentication and groups system to manage access and permissions at the application level.

**Example Code for Audit Trail using Django Signals**
Here's an example of how you might implement audit logging using Django signals:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from yourapp.models import YourDynamicModel, AuditLog

@receiver(post_save, sender=YourDynamicModel)
def log_change(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    AuditLog.objects.create(
        table_name=sender.__name__,
        row_id=instance.pk,
        changed_data={...} # Capture the changed data here
    )
```

**Notes:**

- Performance Considerations: EAV models can be less performant than
  traditional relational models, but with your data size (up to 100k
  rows), this might not be a significant issue.
- Complexity: This approach simplifies some aspects (like dynamic
  schema changes and permissions management) but adds complexity in
  others (like querying and data integrity).
- Scalability: As your application grows, you might need to revisit and
  optimize parts of the architecture.

This strategy balances flexibility with the complexity of your requirements, and aligns well with Django's capabilities and your familiarity with it. Remember, every architectural decision has trade-offs, so it's important to continuously evaluate whether this approach remains the best fit as your application evolves.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: I am exploring the idea of EAV, it seems to make a lot of sense for a dynamic schema. I'm not sure how it will scale but scale is not such an issue. This might be the thing that I'm looking for.